Angular effect() does not redirect to the home page after logout and re-login
I'm using ngrx signal store, and I have a login method that updates my state with isAuthenticated: true and token: token. It also stores the token in localStorage. I have a withComputed((store) => ({ isLogged: computed(() => store.isAuthenticated()) }) setup.
When I log in, my redirectToLoginEffect works correctly and redirects as expected. However, when I call my logout: async () => { } method, which sets isAuthenticated: false and uses router.navigate(['login']) to redirect to the login page, there's an issue when logging back in. Although the token is added to localStorage, the redirectToLoginEffect does not redirect me to the home page as expected. I have to refresh the login page and re-enter my credentials for it to work.
Ngrx Signal Store :
import { computed, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
  patchState,
  signalStore,
  withComputed,
  withHooks,
  withMethods,
  withState,
} from '@ngrx/signals';
import { rxMethod } from '@ngrx/signals/rxjs-interop';
import { pipe, tap, concatMap, map } from 'rxjs';
import { tapResponse } from '@ngrx/operators';
import {
  LocalStorageAuthenticationInfrastructure,
  WithToken,
} from '../services/localstorage.authentication.infrastructure';
import { AuthenticationToken } from '../models/authentication-user';
import { AuthenticationInfrastructure } from '../services/authentication.infrastructure';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

export interface AuthenticationState {
  token: AuthenticationToken | undefined | null;
  isLoading: boolean;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
}

export type AuthenticateType = {
  login: string;
  password: string;
};

const initialValue: AuthenticationState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  token: undefined,
  isLoading: false,
};

export const AuthenticationStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withState(initialValue),
  withComputed((store) => ({
    isLogged: computed(() => store.isAuthenticated()),
    isNotLogged: computed(() => !store.token() || !store.isAuthenticated()),
  })),
  withMethods(
    (
      store,
      infra = inject(AuthenticationInfrastructure),
      localInfra = inject(LocalStorageAuthenticationInfrastructure),
      router = inject(Router)
    ) => ({
      localLogin(token: WithToken): void {
        if (token.access_token) {
          patchState(store, {
            isAuthenticated: true,
            token: {
              access_token: token.access_token,
              expires_in: 0,
              refresh_expires_in: 0,
              refresh_token: '',
            },
          });
        }
      },
      logIn: rxMethod<AuthenticateType>(
        pipe(
          tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true })),
          concatMap((input) => {
            return infra.login(input.login, input.password).pipe(
              map((tokenResponse) => {
                return {
                  access_token: tokenResponse.access_token,
                  expires_in: tokenResponse.expires_in,
                  refresh_expires_in: tokenResponse.refresh_expires_in,
                  refresh_token: tokenResponse.refresh_token,
                } as AuthenticationToken;
              }),
              tap((token) =>
                localInfra.startSession({
                  access_token: token.access_token,
                  refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
                })
              ),
              tapResponse({
                next: (token) => {
                  patchState(store, {
                    isLoading: false,
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                    token: token,
                  });
                },
                error: () => {
                  patchState(store, { isLoading: false });
                },
              })
            );
          })
        )
      ),
      logout: async () => {
        patchState(store, {
          token: undefined,
          isLoading: false,
          isAuthenticated: false,
        });
        console.log("index")
        await localInfra.endSession();
        router.navigate(['login']);
      },
    })
  ),
  withHooks({
    async onInit(
      store,
      localInfra = inject(LocalStorageAuthenticationInfrastructure),
      storage = inject(Storage)
    ) {
      const test = await localInfra.getSession();
      store.localLogin(test);

      // localInfra.getSession().then((token : WithToken ) => {
      //   if (token) {
      //     console.log(token)
      //     store.localLogin(token);
      //   }
      // });
    },
  })
);

Effect Method :
export class AuthenticationApplication {
  private readonly store = inject(AuthenticationStore);
  private readonly router = inject(Router);

  private redirectToLoginEffect = effect(() => {
    if (this.store.isLogged()) {
      this.router.navigate(['tabs']);
    }
  });
}

LocalStorageService :
export class LocalStorageAuthenticationInfrastructure {
  private storageInitialised = false;

  private _storage = inject(Storage);

  async startSession(user: WithToken) {
    if (!this.storageInitialised) await this._storage.create();
    if (user.access_token && user.refresh_token) {
      this._storage?.set('access_token', user.access_token);
      this._storage?.set('refresh_token', user.refresh_token);
    }
  }

  async getSession(): Promise<WithToken> {
    if (!this.storageInitialised) await this._storage.create();
    return {
      access_token: await this._storage?.get('access_token'),
      refresh_token: await this._storage?.get('refresh_token'),
    };
  }

  async endSession(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("clear")
    await this._storage.clear();
  }
}

JWT interceptor that triggers logout when refresh token expires :
export function jwtInterceptor(req: HttpRequest<unknown>,next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  const localStorage = inject(LocalStorageAuthenticationInfrastructure);
  const authInfra = inject(AuthenticationInfrastructure);
  const authApp = inject(AuthenticationApplication);

  return from(localStorage.getSession()).pipe(
    switchMap((token: WithToken) => {
      if (!token.access_token) {
        return next(req);
      }

      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access_token}`,
      });

      const newReq = req.clone({ headers });
      
      return next(newReq).pipe(
        catchError((error) =>{
          if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            switch(error.status){
              case 0:
                console.log("rst")
                return authInfra.refreshToken(token.refresh_token as string).pipe(
                  tap(() => console.log("refreshToken appelé avec le refresh_token :", token.refresh_token)), // Vérifier que la méthode est appelée

                  switchMap((response) =>{
                    localStorage.startSession({
                      access_token: response.access_token,
                      refresh_token: response.refresh_token,
                    })
                    
                    const newReq = req.clone({
                      setHeaders:{
                        'Authorization' : `Bearer ${response.access_token}`
                      }
                    });
    
                    return next(newReq);
                  }),
                  catchError((error) =>{
                    console.log("je suis passé par logout")
                    authApp.logout()
                    return throwError(() => error);
                  })
                )
            }
          }
          return throwError(() => error);
        })
      );
    })
  );
}

My effect doesn't trigger when my state changes. Why do I need to refresh the login page for it to work?

You mentioned that the redirectToLoginEffect doesn't trigger when logging out. The issue could be that the effect is only checking the state on initialization, but the effect doesn't automatically re-run when the state changes. This is because effects in NgRx are typically driven by actions, and your current redirectToLoginEffect might not be responding to changes in the isAuthenticated state.
You should ensure that the effect is triggered whenever the authentication state (isAuthenticated) changes. One way to do this is to explicitly watch for changes in the state by using an Observable that reacts to the state change, rather than checking the state once on initialization.
redirectToLoginEffect:
export class AuthenticationApplication {
  private readonly store = inject(AuthenticationStore);
  private readonly router = inject(Router);

  private redirectToLoginEffect = effect(() => {
    // Trigger this effect whenever `isLogged` changes
    return this.store.isLogged$.pipe(
      tap((isLogged) => {
        if (isLogged) {
          this.router.navigate(['tabs']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      })
    );
  });
}

Here, isLogged$ would be an observable, and the effect will re-run whenever isLogged changes. This will allow you to respond to both login and logout events by redirecting the user to the appropriate page.
Ensure State is Properly Updated During Logout: You mentioned that the logout method works but still doesn't trigger the effect immediately. Check if the state (isAuthenticated and token) is correctly updated during the logout.
logout: async () => {
  patchState(store, {
    token: undefined,
    isLoading: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
  });
  await localInfra.endSession();
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
}

If patchState works as expected, the state will be updated, but the effect might still not trigger unless it's watching for changes.
Force Re-evaluation of the Effect: If your effect is dependent on computed properties like isLogged, and you're using computed values, sometimes changes in state might not propagate as expected because the computed value is cached. To force a re-evaluation, you might need to manually trigger the effect by using an explicit trigger or force re-subscription to the state.
If isLogged() is being used directly in the effect, it may not trigger unless it is re-evaluated. You could either use isLogged$ as an observable that emits new values on state change, or you could refactor to trigger the effect manually when state changes.
State Persistence Across Sessions: Ensure that the local storage data (access_token and refresh_token) is properly read and handled on page reloads. If the onInit lifecycle hook is responsible for checking the session and updating the store, ensure that it correctly updates the store’s state from local storage.
async onInit(store, localInfra = inject(LocalStorageAuthenticationInfrastructure)) {
  const session = await localInfra.getSession();
  if (session.access_token) {
    store.localLogin(session);
  }
}

his ensures that when the page reloads, the session is correctly reloaded, and the isAuthenticated state is set correctly.

Thank you for your response! I have a question regarding "watch for changes in the state by using an Observable." Is it possible to monitor isLogged using a pipe, given that isLogged returns a Boolean Signal?
Otherwise, my logout method works well: it updates the states, deletes the localStorage, logs me out, and redirects to the login page. When I click the "logout" button, it clears the token in localStorage, logs me out, and redirects to the login page. After that, if I enter my credentials, I can log in without any issues.

My issue occurs when an error is intercepted by the JwtInterceptor, indicating that the refresh token has expired. In this case, I call the authApp.logout() method, which logs me out, clears the tokens in localStorage, and redirects to the login page. However, if I try to log back in immediately after, the tokens are saved again in localStorage, but the redirection to the home page doesn’t work unless I refresh the page. When I call authApp.logout() via the logout button, everything works as expected.

It seems like the issue you’re encountering happens after the JWT refresh token expires and the authApp.logout() method is called. In this case, even though you're correctly updating the state, clearing the local storage, and navigating to the login page, the redirection to the home page after logging in again does not trigger automatically unless the page is refreshed.
To address this, there are a few things you can investigate:

Reactive Computed Value for isLogged
Since isLogged is a computed signal, it is likely that the isLogged computed value doesn't emit new changes unless it's explicitly observed in a reactive way. Signals in NgRx are not always automatically subscribed to unless explicitly done so, and computed signals are cached until there’s an actual subscription that triggers a re-evaluation.

You need to ensure that your redirectToLoginEffect is properly reacting to changes in the isLogged signal. However, as you mentioned that isLogged is a Boolean Signal, and Signals don't emit by default like Observables, you need to wrap your isLogged signal in an Observable to reactively subscribe to it.
Here’s how you can modify your effect to observe the changes in isLogged:

Use withComputed for Signal-based Observables
In NgRx Signal Store, withComputed doesn't create an observable directly. You’ll need to create an observable from the computed value so that your effect can react to it. You can achieve this by converting the signal to an observable.
import { fromSignal } from '@ngrx/signals';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';
export class AuthenticationApplication {
private readonly store = inject(AuthenticationStore);
private readonly router = inject(Router);
private redirectToLoginEffect = effect(() => {
return fromSignal(this.store.isLogged).pipe(  // Convert signal to observable
tap((isLogged) => {
if (isLogged) {
this.router.navigate(['tabs']);
} else {
this.router.navigate(['login']);
}
})
);
});
}


In this solution, fromSignal(this.store.isLogged) converts the signal to an observable that emits whenever isLogged changes. This way, the effect will automatically trigger when the login or logout state changes.

Ensure Correct Sequence of State and Navigation
Make sure that the state updates (like isAuthenticated and token) happen before the navigation in your logout method. Since the navigation relies on the updated state to trigger the redirection, it’s important that the state is completely updated before you navigate.

You can update the logout method like this:
logout: async () => {
  patchState(store, {
    token: undefined,
    isLoading: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
  });
  
  await localInfra.endSession();

  // Use a delay or the 'state update complete' signal to ensure state change before navigation
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }, 0);
}

This ensures that the state change is fully committed before the navigation happens, reducing the chances of navigation issues caused by asynchronous state updates.

Review the JwtInterceptor Error Handling Flow
In the case of the refresh token expiration, you’re using the jwtInterceptor to handle the token expiration and logout process. It looks like the sequence might be causing some issues. Specifically, you’re calling authApp.logout() directly in the interceptor, which is correct for clearing the session, but the effect that handles navigation might not be running as expected because it's not reacting to the state changes.

You might want to add a manual trigger or ensure that the state change is fully propagated through the system before triggering the redirection. Since the interceptor is dealing with asynchronous operations (like calling logout after the token refresh fails), it might be worth introducing a slight delay before navigation.

Force Re-checking of the State in Interceptor
When handling the JWT error in the interceptor, you can explicitly check if the logout state has changed before performing the redirection:
catchError((error) => {
console.log("Refresh token expired, logging out...");
authApp.logout();  // Clear session and navigate to login
// Add a small delay or force a re-evaluation of the navigation
setTimeout(() => {
this.router.navigate(['login']);
}, 0);
return throwError(() => error);
})


This ensures that the state is reset and the navigation is processed properly.

Investigate withComputed Behavior
Finally, it’s important to check how withComputed and your isLogged signal interact with the state. When you use withComputed, ensure that your computed values are re-evaluated as expected and that there are no caching issues. If the signal is too "sticky" (i.e., it doesn't emit updated values), the navigation effect might not trigger as expected.

Make sure that isLogged is being properly observed and that it reacts to both login and logout changes. Also, remember that computed() doesn't automatically trigger re-renders unless it is accessed or subscribed to.
Final Steps
1-Convert Signal to Observable (fromSignal) in your effect to ensure reactive state updates.
2-Ensure state is updated properly before navigation in the logout method.
3-Check your JwtInterceptor to ensure that the redirection happens after the state is updated.
4-Investigate withComputed caching issues and ensure it properly reacts to state changes.
By doing this, the navigation to the home page should work without requiring a page refresh.

"I think I’ve understood part of the problem. It actually comes from the lifecycle of my Home component. When I log in for the first time, I’m redirected to this component, where a store is instantiated. This store allows me to launch the loadCurrentUser method via the WithHooks and OnInit hooks.

However, when I log out and log back in, the OnInit hook no longer works because it was already triggered once. How could I destroy this component upon logout?"

Ah, I see! The issue you're describing stems from how Angular’s component lifecycle works, especially regarding OnInit and re-initializing the component. Since the OnInit lifecycle hook only triggers when the component is instantiated, it doesn't fire again if the component stays in memory after logging out and logging back in. In your case, since the component isn't destroyed when logging out, the OnInit hook doesn't run again after logging back in.
To solve this problem, you can handle the component destruction and re-instantiation in a few ways, but let’s focus on one of the more effective strategies for this scenario.

Using router-outlet and Navigating Away from the Home Component
One of the most straightforward ways to "destroy" a component is to navigate away from it and re-navigate to it when needed. When you navigate to another route, Angular removes the current component from the view, and when you navigate back, the component is re-created, which triggers the OnInit hook again.

Here’s how you can modify your navigation logic to ensure the component is destroyed and recreated:
Navigate Away on Logout: When the user logs out, navigate to a route that is not the home page, such as the login page.
Re-Navigate to the Home Page on Login: After the user logs in successfully, navigate back to the home page.
For example, update your logout method like this:
logout: async () => {
  patchState(store, {
    token: undefined,
    isLoading: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
  });

  await localInfra.endSession();

  // Navigate away from the home page to destroy the component
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
};

Then, after successful login:
loginSuccess: (token) => {
  patchState(store, {
    isAuthenticated: true,
    token: token,
  });

  // Navigate back to the home page after login
  this.router.navigate(['home']);  // or the route for the home page
};


Using ngIf to Dynamically Destroy the Component
Another approach is to dynamically control the existence of the component in the DOM using *ngIf. This way, the component will be completely destroyed (and its lifecycle hooks will be re-triggered) when the user logs out.

In your app template:
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
  <app-home></app-home>
</ng-container>

In your component class (likely in the parent component or a layout component):
export class AppComponent {
  isLoggedIn = false; // or your signal/store that tracks authentication

  constructor(private store: AuthenticationStore) {
    // Subscribe to store or use the computed signal
    this.store.isLogged$.subscribe((loggedIn) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
    });
  }
}

Here, when isLoggedIn is set to false, the app-home component will be destroyed, and when it is set back to true, the component will be recreated, and its lifecycle hooks (like OnInit) will be triggered again.

Using ngOnDestroy in Your Component
If you want to ensure that the component cleans up any resources or subscriptions when it’s destroyed, you can use the ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook to manually handle cleanup:
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
ngOnInit() {
// Initial setup for the component
}
ngOnDestroy() {
// Cleanup code here when the component is destroyed
console.log('HomeComponent destroyed');
}
}

Leveraging Router Navigation with runGuardsAndResolvers
If you need to ensure that a route's guards or resolvers are re-triggered after login, you can use runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange' in your route configuration.


In your routing module, configure the route for the home page like this:
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: 'home',
component: HomeComponent,
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange',  // Ensures re-running of guards/resolvers when params change
},
];
This will trigger route guards and resolvers on navigating back to the home page after login, and you can use it to control whether you want to fetch user data again, etc.

Triggering OnInit Manually
If you want more control, and you don't want to rely on Angular's lifecycle hooks or routing system to trigger re-instantiation, you can manually call the ngOnInit method again after a state change. However, this is not a recommended approach, as it violates Angular’s lifecycle management principles, but it is an option if needed.

For example:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // Code to initialize the component
    console.log('HomeComponent initialized');
  }

  refreshComponent() {
    this.ngOnInit();  // Manually call ngOnInit
  }
}

Then, after logging in, you can call refreshComponent() manually if the component is still active but needs to be re-initialized.
Summary
Navigate Away and Back: The most natural way in Angular is to navigate away from the home component and then back again to ensure that it gets re-instantiated, which will trigger the OnInit hook.
Use *ngIf: Dynamically destroy and recreate the component by toggling its existence in the DOM with *ngIf.
ngOnDestroy for Cleanup: Ensure proper cleanup of resources when the component is destroyed.
Use Guards or Resolvers: Re-run route guards or resolvers if needed when re-navigating to the home page.
By implementing one of these strategies, you can ensure that your OnInit hook is triggered properly when the user logs in again after logging out, without requiring a full page refresh.

I forgot to mention, but I'm using Ionic Framework, which handles the lifecycle differently from Angular for better optimization. For example, if I navigate from one page to another via the route, my component isn't destroyed, it's just hidden, if I understood correctly

sorry bro but i don't have much idea or experience in Ionic Framework
